# Is using AtomicInteger in a java multithreading program slower and inefficient than other methods of synchronization?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am carrying out an experiment with two multithreading java programs. I have one that is not synchronized and another that is using `AtomicInteger`. The `AtomicInteger` is much slower. I think this might be because of the method `AtomicInteger` uses `compareAndset()`. Am I correct?

Comment: Your question title and your question are completely different.  Is `AtomicInteger` slower than _no_ synchronization?  Absolutely.  Is `AtomicInteger` faster than other kinds of synchronization?  Maybe.  (Is complete non-synchronization acceptable in concurrent applications?  Rarely if ever.)

Comment: +1 @Louis.  There's not much point in comparing performance between a correct program and an incorrect program.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, the safety of synchronization comes with some performance cost. For example, see [Cost of synchronization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4354677/130224).

Answer (score 1):

The `AtomicInteger` class and its siblings will be as fast as any equivalent functionality you can write in pure Java, and will often be faster, because they are likely to be able to use native instructions available on the platform.

Whenever you are writing a concurrent program, use the `java.util.concurrency` package. It's more robust *and* more efficient than anything you'll write with `synchronized` or `volatile`.

An operation by one thread is only guaranteed to be visible to another thread if both threads use suitable memory barriers. For example, writing and reading a `volatile` variable, or entering a `synchronized` block. Skipping memory barriers will be faster, but since your program is broken, your efficiency is zero.